# Navigation drawer hidden by MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am fairly new to Android and am using Navigation drawers for the first time. I think I have something messed up.  When I open my application the fields on my main activities XML layout display fine.  However, when I select the navigation drawer it comes up behind the main form which appears to be semi-transparent.  I cannot select any of the options on the Navigation Drawer.

Do I need to move the UI and associated code that was on the mainActivity.java and mainactivity.xml into a fragment and load that by default?  Is there something wrong with my mainactivity.xml shown below?

Thanks,

Jerry

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using 
  match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.developer.symptom.androidclient.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.developer.symptom.androidclient.NavigationDrawerFragment" />

<!-- views used by main activity     -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="gone">

    <!-- Welcome message   -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"  android:text="Welcome" 
      android:id="@+id/main_welcome"/>

    <!-- Data of birth and medical record number -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth_prompt"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/main_date_of_birth"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/med_rec_number_prompt"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/main_med_rec_num"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the `MainActivity` code please?

Comment: @JerryKur I believe your nav drawer layout needs to be the second item within DrawerLayout, not the first. Also, you should only have 2 children within DrawerLayout. Why do you have 3?

Comment: Justin  - Intellij generated the FrameLayout and fragment elements.  I inserted the LinearLayout.  Is this my error?  Can I put the LinearLayout and it's views after the DrawerLayout?  Or do I need to put that layout and associated code into a new fragment, ex home.xml and homefrag.java?

Comment: There can only be 2 children in `DrawerLayout` your content should go in a fragment in that framelayout

Comment: Ok.  I will do that.  It makes perfect sense to have it in a separate fragment now that I look at.

Comment: Justin - you first put me onto 3 children instead of two.  If you put in a answer I can accept it.  Thanks again.